# c++: Any way to avoid typing the class name before every member function?

Tags: c++, member-functions

I started out programming 5 years ago in java, so when I moved over to c++ 2 years ago, implementations of member functions were rather irritating.

```
Foo::bar(){/*some stuff*/}
Foo::baz(){/*some other stuff*/}
```

Back then I just kinda got used to it, but recently I wondered if there was any way to structure code to avoid typing that Foo:: every function, perhaps something like:

```
Foo::{
    bar(){//some stuff}
    baz(){//some other stuff}
}
```

I've found that even after 2 years I still have trouble reading even my own code because the name of the function itself isn't the first thing in the line.

edit: Since this question is a duplicate, I thought I would share one thing I found clicking on links. This is definitively not possible at the moment, but there is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0223r0.html) to add it to the standard. Don't know if or when it might actually get added, but if you're reading this a few years from now this could be a good lead.

Comment: but writing public or private everywhere is not irritating ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not (unless you define a member function contextually with its declaration, thus when you define your class - that is more or less what happens in Java actually).

In other terms, if you don't want to do this:

```
// .h
struct S { void f(); };
// .cpp
void S::f() {}
```

You can still do this:

```
// .h
struct S { void f() {} };
```

Anyway it has drawbacks and you could not be prepared to deal with them in any situation.

Comment: Problem is that your examples are not completely equal.

Comment: @Logman:  The second increases likelihood that calls to `S::f()` can be inlined, but the two are functionally equivalent.

Comment: I would also like to be able to keep the class declaration and the implementation separate. I take it that I can't have my cake and eat it in this case?